# Set Class-Path as Rsrc-Class-Path in Maven jar build

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have build a maven jar. The manifest looks like

```
Build-Jdk: 1.7.0_55
Main-Class: com.abc.Locator
Class-Path: ./ lib/activemq-all-5.8.0.jar lib/activemq-amqp-5.8.0.jar 
 lib/activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar lib/activemq-openwire-legacy-5.8.0.jar
```

But I want the jar manifest should have Rsrc-Class-Path in place of Class-Path.

```
Rsrc-Class-Path: ./ lib/activemq-all-5.8.0.jar lib/activemq-amqp-5.8.0.jar l
 ib/activemq-broker-5.8.0.jar lib/activemq-openwire-legacy-5.8.0.jar l
 ib/proton-jms-0.3.0-fuse-2.jar lib/proton-0.3.0-fuse-2.jar lib/proton

 Class-Path: .
```

Is it possible using Maven-jar-plugin or I need to have a custom maven plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to mvn [documentation](http://maven.apache.org/shared/maven-archiver/examples/manifestFile.html) you might use your own MANIFEST file.